# How can I collaborate and code when someone is using Eclipse and another using Android Studio?

Tags: android, eclipse, android-studio

I have a developer who is using a Macbook and Eclipse, while I am on a windows computer using android studio. We are attempting to work on the same code using Github, however it seems that egit and android are quite different? Does anyone know how to work around this?

Comment: there is no automatic way(AFAIK) to import the eclipse project directly into Android Studio. I think one of you will have to shift to  other's IDE.

Comment: thanks for the quick response. But hmmm yea i think thats what i figured. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You should switch to using the Gradle build system (see [these instructions for migrating your build from Eclipse to Gradle](http://tools.android.com/tech-docs/new-build-system/migrating-from-eclipse-projects)) which can be built from the command line. You would then have Android Studio build the project using Gradle, and you would also use the [Eclipse Plugin for Gradle](http://www.gradle.org/docs/current/userguide/eclipse_plugin.html) to generate the Eclipse project from the Gradle configuration. In short, Gradle would be the canonical description (in your repository) for the project, and you would have both Eclipse and Android Studio use the Gradle configuration for building the project. You will probably also want to configure Git to ignore and exclude the Eclipse project generated by this configuration.

Comment: Thanks for the quick response Michael! So in theory if the project was uploaded and synced to github before switching to the Gradle system the only way an android studio developer would be able to work on it is if he installed and switched to eclipse?

Comment: Well, the Android Studio person could also use the Android SDK tools on the commandline, but yeah, it wouldn't be particularly pleasant. Best to convert to Gradle, submit the Gradle configuration, and remove the Eclipse configuration from the repository.

Comment: This is unlikely to work. I don't think the Eclipse plugin for Gradle understands Android-Gradle projects, which don't use normal Java sourcesets and are otherwise much more complex.